# How do I run simulations on rails? (e.g. sports/stock market/etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simulation

I'm interested in creating some web apps that simulate results based on data. For example, a baseball or stock market simulation, but I mostly have experience creating social apps/widgets in rails.

Any ideas of some resources I could check out? I've been looking through google, and theres some physicsy offline ruby stuff, but I'm still a bit lost.

I would imagine I'd have to aggregate a lot of statistical data, and then run it through various simulation algorithms.

I'd appreciate a push in the right direction, thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you give some specific examples of what you're trying to accomplish?

"Creating web apps that simulate results based on data" is pretty vague. Are you just feeding data to some sort of UI component on a web page? Or are you trying to do some number crunching and store the results into a database?

Comment: sorry for lack of clarification, i'd be feeding data to some sort of UI component, the new app would likely be a game

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, Rails is designed to mostly do its computing between a web request and response, so you could use something like a [**queue**](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/queueing.html) or a [**daemonizer**](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/daemonizing.html) to run your simulations in the background.

For another, Rails is light on routines for numerical computing, so you could use [**ruby-gsl**](http://ruby-gsl.sourceforge.net/), a ruby port of the GNU Scientific Library. There are lots of goodies in there for simulators, including the standard statistics routines and support for the Monte Carlo algorithm.

Comment: appreciate your help, i will look into those!